# linux kernel socket source macro container_of

Tags: c, sockets, kernel

i was trying to understand how  created is socket but i have ran  into the  problem which i really dont understand. This problem is the code below:

```
static inline struct socket *SOCKET_I(struct inode *inode)
{
    return &container_of(inode, struct socket_alloc, vfs_inode)->socket; //why here is -> socket
}
```

I see it's the `container_of` macro and it returns  a pointer. It takes `inode`  pointer as a parameter  and
subtracts amount of `vfs_inode` bytes.

my question is :
Why there is something like `->socket` at the end of the macro  and what does it do?

Comment: "Why there is something like `->socket` at the end of the macro and what does it do?" - `->socket` is NOT a part of the macro invocation. Assume the macro returns a pointer (of type `inode*`), and you name that return value as `inode_object`. So you may write return statement as `&inode_object->socket`. That is, this is just a pointer to the `socket` field.

Comment: so this macro is  returning inode pointer which is pointing to the socket  struct ? . It takes pointer to the inode and substract amount of vfs_inode bytes then this pointer is pointing to the socket?. Iam right ?

Comment: If by "`vfs_inode` bytes" you mean **offset** of `vfs_inode` field inside `socket_alloc` structure, then yes, `container_of` subtracts given amount from the input pointer and return result of subtraction casted to `struct socket_alloc*`.

Comment: I have 1 more question about this input pointer. As i know pointer have some adress  and  SOCKET_I takes pointer with some adress and then substract this adress from bytes.  and return socket_alloc* as u said. How did it know that this adress - amount of bytes will be  struct socket_alloc*. I mean without  setting this pointer points to the vfs_inode/

Comment: im little confused cuz i cant meet any inode pointer to the member

Comment: It is **usage requirement** of `SOCKET_I` function, that it should be called only with `inode` parameter pointing to the field `vfs_inode` of some `socket_alloc` object. You may wonder how one could obtain pointer-to-the-field of the object without using the pointer to the object. But actually this is quite common scenario in the Linux kernel used for Object Oriented Programming (OOP), when a virtual method is called with a pointer to the object of the base type, and in the implementation of this method for derived type you need to cast this pointer-to-base-type to the pointer-to-derived-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code which helps me to understand it more  in kernel linux there is function like sock_alloc_inode which return &ei->vfs_inode nad i think linux kernel scenario with container of macro in socket.c may looks like that. Im not sure if its right but looks well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




#define offsetof(type, member) ((size_t) &((type *)0)->member)
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                          \
        const typeof ( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);       \
        (type *) ( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type, member) ); })


struct inode{

  int a;
  int b;

};
struct socket{

  int some_other_data;
  int this_data;

};
struct socket_alloc{
    struct socket socket ;
    struct inode vfs_inode;

};
static inline struct socket *SOCKET_I(struct inode *inode)
{
    return &container_of(inode, struct socket_alloc, vfs_inode)->socket;
}
static inline struct inode *SOCK_INODE(struct socket *socket)
{
    return &container_of(socket, struct socket_alloc, socket)->vfs_inode;
}
int main()
{
    struct inode *inode;
    struct socket* socket;
    struct socket_alloc *ei;
    ei = (struct socket_alloc*)malloc(sizeof(*ei));
    inode = (struct inode*)malloc(sizeof(*inode));
    socket = (struct socket*)malloc(sizeof(*socket));
    printf("INODE POINTER NO MACRO AND  WITHOUT REFER TO THE SOCKET_ALLOC STRUCT     %d\n", *inode);
    inode= &ei->vfs_inode;

    printf("INODE POINTER NO MACRO %d\n", *inode);
    printf("SOCKET POINTER NO MACRO%d\n", *socket);

    socket = SOCKET_I(inode);
    inode = SOCK_INODE(socket);

     printf("INODE POINTER USING MACRO %d\n", *inode);
     printf("SOCKET POINTER USING MACRO %d\n", *socket);

    free(ei);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`inode` is the `vfs_inode` member of a `socket_alloc` structure. `container_of` expands to the structure that contains that member.

The structure also contains a `socket` member, and this function returns the value of that member.

In other words, there's a structure like

```
struct socket_alloc {
    // ... some members
    struct inode vfs_inode;
    // ... other members
    struct socket socket
    // ... more members
} some_variable;
```

If you do:

```
struct inode *i = &(some_variable.vfs_inode);
```

then you can later do

```
struct socket *this_sock = SOCKET_I(i);
```

to get a pointer to the corresponding `socket`.

Comment: In socket source code there is no something like `struct inode *i = &(some_variable.vfs_inode); ` And im wondering why it works i mean if inode is some random adress and macro substract this adress and amount of bytes of vfs_inode how did it know that this random adress - offsetof vfs_inode will be pointing to socket.

Comment: i mean how it know that random adress - offsetof vfs_inode macro will be pointing to structure socket_alloc and this will be pointing to structure socket of this socket _alloc structure

Comment: `offsetof` tells you the number of bytes from the beginning of the structure to the member. So if you have a pointer to the member and subtract the offset, you get a pointer to the beginning of the struct.